# Can I programmatically create a C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

For example: can I create a "Hello World" console application from another C# application and build it?

I want to create a simple automated process that creates .NET projects without Visual Studio and build them.

Comment: Question is way to broad to begin with.

Comment: Yes, you can. Another question?

Comment: Look into code generation tools like CodeDom, T4 and Expressions (edit: this will only generate the code, not the project files).

Comment: Can you give some details about the nature of the projects? For instance, would the code be derived from data, or a DSL or other specification of what's to be created? Also, realize that MSBUILD is what builds VS projects to begin with, and it's part of the .NET SDK. There's no reason you couldn't create some code files, create an MSBUILD project to collect them, then build it. The level of sanity involved would be the greater question.

Comment: I don't think this question is unreasonable at all. All he's really asking is how to automatically generate .NET applications. Why all the close votes?

Comment: Yes you can compile .cs files created in some text editor and compile them using csc.exe provided in .Net Framework.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen As you can see from the close vote reasons, this is "too broad".  What's unreasonable is providing an entire topic area and saying, "teach me this whole thing".  There's simply too much information to cover to provide a complete answer, and we don't want questions that only attract incomplete answers.  The question needs to be focused, perhaps to a specific problem he is having in the process of programmatically generating a C# project, for example.

Comment: I agree with you guys.Basically I can created code dynamical using CodeDome then compile using specific commands. Alright. My "real" task isn't easy but is not impossible. Next time I will ask more specific question. I just didn't know where to start with this and google didn't help me.

Comment: @Servy: Maybe his question was worded badly but I still think it's reasonable. All he really seemed to want was a pointer for compiling things programmatically.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen That's not what he is asking for at all.  If that's what he actually wants then he should be rephrasing his question into one that is focused, clear, and answerable.  If so, it may be reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you really need to do is have your program create a .cs source file with the source you want and run it through the command line compiler.

[csc.exe (Microsoft's compiler)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

[Mono's compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler)

You can also use [CodeDom](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655) to access the C# compiler from code.

If you absolutely must have an entire .NET project, make a minimal .csproj file and use that as a template. You can build them with [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [XBuild](http://mono-project.com/Porting_MSBuild_Projects_To_XBuild).